# Разделить ссылку от запятой пробелом

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть кастомная форма комментариев. При написании комментария, если пользователь сразу после ссылки поставит любой знак препинания (`,` или `.` или `!` и тд.), то при публикации знак препинания станет частью ссылки, и естественно ссылка будет не рабочей. Можно ли как-то устранить проблему? Приведу часть кода:

```
<div class="comment">
<?php
    if (!empty($comment_html)) {
        $m = '|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
        $r = '<noindex><a href="$0" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$0</a></noindex>';

        $comment_html = preg_replace($m, $r, $comment_html);
    }
    if (empty($comment_html)) {
        $m = '|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
        $r = '<noindex><a href="$0" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$0</a></noindex>';

        $comment_html = preg_replace($m, $r, $comment->comment_content);
    }
    if ($comment_html == "Комментарий удален.") {
        echo '<span>' . $comment_html . '</span>';
    } else {
        echo $comment_html;
        
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подправьте регулярное выражение. Замените строку

```
$m = '|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
```

на

```
$m = '|(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\W\D]*/?)|i';
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но если ставить "!" то перейдет по ссылке с ошибкой: "https://www.youtube.com%21/". С запятой: "https://www.youtube.com%2C/".

Comment: И почему то если до ссылки стоит слово состоящее из англ. букв, то оно тоже становиться ссылкой. Но это ладно, это было до вашего кода )

Comment: @АннаМатвеева подправил ответ. Проверил у себя, работает. Заодно и Вашу проблему с "приклеиванием" слова решил :-)
P.S. Не люблю регулярки бррррр :-)